# Выборка данных из БД mysql используя русские слова

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой выборки данных из БД при использовании запроса с русскими буквами.

Есть БД test в кодировке **utf8_general_ci**, в ней таблица так же в кодировке **utf8_general_ci**. В таблице 2 столбца eng и rus в которых данные:

```
eng rus
GGGG ГГГГГ
GGGG ГГГГ
```

и есть php код

```
<?php
$dbname = 'test';
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db($dbname,$link);

if (!$link) {
    echo 'Ошибка подключения к mysql';
exit;
    }

$sql = "SELECT count(*) from `test` WHERE `eng` like 'ГГ%'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$k_el = $row[0];
echo $k_el;
?>
```

При использовании sql запроса

```
SELECT count(*) from `test` WHERE `eng` like 'ГГ%'
```

Выдает: 0
При использовании запроса

```
SELECT count(*) from `test` WHERE `eng` like 'GG%'
```

Выдает 2, как и положено.

Т.е. не идет выборка по русским буквам из БД.

Если делать базу и таблицы в **cp_1251_general_ci**
то выдает ошибку

> Illegal mix of collations (cp1251_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'

Проблема в кодировке, но как это исправить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
mysql_select_db($dbname,$link);
```

добавь строку

```
 mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо большое.

Comment: не забудьте отметить как правильный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы решили, что проблема в кодировке? Вы ведь ищете, судя по коду, только в столбце **eng**, а там никаких ГГ нет - всё верно.

Попробуйте выполнить запрос `SELECT count(*) from test WHERE rus like 'ГГ%'`
Наверняка, вернётся 2 строки, как и должно.

Ну и рекомендую почитать [документацию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html), чтобы понять что такое collation вообще и на что оно влияет.

Comment: Это просто опечатался, в итоге все равно возвращает 0. Помог коммент выше, где надо указать mysql_set_charset("utf8");